# How to turn recursion sum formula into an integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have a formula that looks a lot like integral:
$$
  m(t) =  \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \sum_{i \in \{\Delta t, 2\Delta t, ... ,t\} } ( m (i - \Delta t) + v(i)) \, \Delta t
$$
where $v(t) = \text{const}$, $m(0)$ is given. 
Yet I wonder - how to turn it into an integral and is it possible when to calculate $m(t)$ I have to obtain $m\left(t- \Delta t\right)$ ?

Comment: Without any context we can't help you. What is "Pr(t)"? What is "n(t)"? What is "v(t)"? Where is "i" used in the sum?

Comment: They are functions that depend only on time

Comment: simplified a bit

Answer (score 0):

The right side of your formula is a limit. If that limit exists, then it is an integral as you suggested. $\, m(t) = \int_0^t m(x) + v(x)\, dx. \,$ Your question about $\, m(t-\Delta t) \,$ turns out not to be a problem because in the limit that is the same as $\, m(t). \,$ Taking the derivative of both sides of the equation, $\, m'(t) = m(t) + v(t) \,$ which is a simple differential equation with initial value $\, m(0)=0. \,$

Comment: but how to show that $m(x)$ has $x$ that is less than $v(x)$ and thus $m(x)$ has to be acquired on previous integration step?

Comment: @DuckQueen What does "m(x) has x that is less than v(x)" mean? What previous integration step? Your comment does not make sense to me. Put your sensible comment in the question itself if it is important to you.